# WooCommerce checkout - how to give free shipping for a specific address

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, checkout

The following code will allow free shipping for a specific product:

```
    function wcs_my_free_shipping( $is_available ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // set the product ids that are eligible
    $eligible = array( '360' );

    // get cart contents
    $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    // loop through the items looking for one in the eligible array
    foreach ( $cart_items as $key => $item ) {
        if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $eligible ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // nothing found return the default value
    return $is_available;
   }
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'wcs_my_free_shipping', 20 );
```

What I would like to do is allow free shipping not for a product, but for a specific street and zip code combination in the delivery address.  I found out how to check this for a logged-in user, but can't seem to find the right variables that have this information at checkout.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
-Ben

Comment: change the `foreach(){}` with your logic of checking the address. `return true` means it's a free shipping.

Answer (score 0):

There are Shipping zones available in Woocommerce already. For each specific zone you can set the shipping method either "Flat rate" or "Free Shipping". You can check it under Woocommerce->Settings. Find Shipping tab.

[Screenshot for shipping tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSbnA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there is an extra parameter you can pass into this hook names $package.
for eg.

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'wcs_my_free_shipping', 20,2 );

function wcs_my_free_shipping( $is_available, $package){
//Your code for free shipping  for a selected address found in $package
return $is_available
}
```

**$package** contains the address you entered so you can use this to apply free shipping for selected zip codes or streets